# Case insensitive comparisons across locales in Java

Tags: java, localization, linguistics

Considering the following Java code comparing a small string containing the [German grapheme ß](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F)

```
String a = "ß";
String b = a.toUpperCase();

assertTrue(a.equalsIgnoreCase(b));
```

The comparison fails, because "ß".toUpperCase() is actually equal to "SS", and that ends up failing a check in `equalsIgnoreCase()`. The Javadocs for `toUpperCase()` do mention this case explicitly, however I don't understand why this does not go to ẞ, [the capital variant of ß](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E)?

More generally, how should we do case insensitive comparisons, potentially across different locales. Should we just always use either `toUpper()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()`, but never both?

It seems that the problem is that the implementation of `equalsIgnoreCase()` includes the following check: `anotherString.value.length == value.length`, which seems incompatible with the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase-java.util.Locale-) for `toUpper()`, which state:

> Since case mappings are not always 1:1 char mappings, the resulting
>   String may be a different length than the original String.

Comment: You would need to use a [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) instead of the built-in methods of `String`.

Comment: `SS` is the uppercase because [it's defined to be in Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00df/index.htm).

Comment: @AndyTurner that's weird, because there is a Unicode code point for the upper case character, and it defines this character as it's lower case character http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1e9e/index.htm

Comment: @AndyTurner Is this just to do with the fact that the capital was introduced in 2008, and the original in 1993?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java's [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) class is designed for different locale-sensitive text comparison operations. Since the concept of "upper-case" varies quite a bit between locales, `Collator` uses a more fine-grained model called comparison *strength*. There are four levels provided, and how they affect comparisons is locale-dependent.

Here's an example of using `Collator` with the German locale for case-insensitive comparison of the letter `ß`:

```
Collator germanCollator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
int[] strengths = new int[] {Collator.PRIMARY, Collator.SECONDARY,
                             Collator.TERTIARY, Collator.IDENTICAL};

String a = "ß";
String b = "ß".toUpperCase();

for (int strength : strengths) {
    germanCollator.setStrength(strength);
    if (germanCollator.compare(a, b) == 0) {
        System.out.println(String.format(
                "%s and %s are equivalent when comparing differences with "
                + "strength %s using the GERMAN locale.",
                a, b, String.valueOf(strength)));
    }
}
```

The code prints out

```
ß and SS are equivalent when comparing differences with strength 0 using the GERMAN locale.
ß and SS are equivalent when comparing differences with strength 1 using the GERMAN locale.
```

which means that the German locale considers these two strings equal in `PRIMARY` and `SECONDARY` strength comparisons.